# Instalar Leaflet en Angular 4

Tags: angular4, leaflet

soy nuevo en Angular, y no estoy pudiendo instalar la librería Leaflet, con las mismas llamadas a la librería que uso en HTML no me funcionan en angular,quería saber si alguien sabe como hacer para instalarlo. Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes installar el paquete usando:

```
 npm install leaflet --save
```

Cuando se instale el paquete, debes poder ingresar la ruta para los archivos de estilo y script encontrados en node_modules, yendo a `angular-cli.json` en las secciones: `"styles": []` y `"scripts": []`

> Recuerda que Angular utiliza Angular-CLI - Mas información [aqui](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation[])

**Si desea importar el paquete en un módulo existente**

En la parte superior de tu módulo escribe:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
```

Comment: Voy a probar, gracias

Comment: Recuerda puntuar y marcar como correcta si te sirvió la respuesta, para los próximos que tengan este inconveniente. Saludos.